# impressions from text

Tags: web-services, artificial-intelligence

is there an open source library or web service that i can feed with text and get back the overall impression ? by impression i mean the emotional state, what the person who wrote the text happy,sad..etc

Comment: You probably mean the emotion that the text invokes inside the reader?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/sentiment-opinion-mining/overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not that simple - writer could feel several emotions at-once and besides writer emotions could vary with different parts of text ...

In general you can start to dig the problem from these articles:

- [Emotions from text: machine learning for text-based emotion prediction](http://l2r.cs.uiuc.edu/%7Edanr/Papers/AlmRoSp05.pdf)
- [Identifying Expressions of Emotion in Text](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-74628-7_27)
- [Context Based Emotion Detection from Text Input](https://web.archive.org/web/20131102043850/http://mir.cs.nthu.edu.tw:80/users/peggy/homepage/paper/Spec4302p.4_p1120.pdf)

hth!